# SQLite WAL mode and read-modify-write operations with side effects

Tags: sqlite, synchronization

I'm new to SQLite.

Say a row in your table has a column `status` that is persisting a state-machine. A typical operation on such a row would be to read the current state, and set the next state depending on that, the code having some side-effects.

In a transaction:

```
val state = db.execute("SELECT state FROM ...")
if (state == "READY_TO_SEND") {
    .... do some side-effecting stuff, like sending an email ...
    db.execute("UPDATE ... SET state = "MAIL_SENT")
}
```

In Postgres I could pessimistically lock the row using "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" to synchronize in this case.

In case of SQLite with WAL mode enabled, if I understood correctly, the read of the current state could happen concurrently by two transactions. Both threads would create the side-effects. Then both transaction would want to upgrade to write. One of them will succeed at an upgrade, the other not, but it's too late to synchronize the side-effects.

Did I understand the SQLite isolation mechanism correctly?

How would you go about synchronization in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your example there would be no issue.

If both reads were concurrent and read the same row(s) both would want to update and set the state from **"READY_TO_SEND"** to **"MAIL_SENT"**. Even if the updates ran concurrently the concurrency would be disturbed as only 1 writer can run at a time. Thus both updates would be applied but sequentially (even though only 1 would be required) and then end result would be the same.

- *However, since there is only one WAL file, there can only be one writer at a time.*
  [SQLite - Write-Ahead-Logging](https://sqlite.org/wal.html)

Perhaps a bigger issue/side affect could be if the update where `UPDATE .... SET state = 'MAIL_SENT' WHERE state = 'READY_TO_SEND';` and the result of the update (number of rows updated) where then used to indicate if the email where sent. The 2nd could be **0** as the WHERE clause would then supress the update. Thus the result from the update might lead to an indication that the email was not sent when it has been sent.

- However, this would be a design issue as obviously they are separate emails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem I see is that an email is sent twice for a single row in my example. But I think I found a way to avoid that by beginning a "immediate" mode transaction, then writers call be locked out before any other processing is done.